# Unicorn doesn't run in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, unicorn

I am running stack nginx+unicorn+rails 3.2

When I am running

```
bundle exec unicorn_rails -c config/unicorn.rb -E development
```

it is ok, and site running well

when I am trying start unicorn site in production mode

```
bundle exec unicorn_rails -c config/unicorn.rb -E production
```

I have "We're sorry, but something went wrong." error:

[image]

Comment: What does your log say?

Comment: no messages in development.log,production.log,unicorn_error.log,unicorn.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was in script precompilation. It was solved by adding to "config/environments/production.rb" following line:

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you run migrations for production?

```
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV="production"
```

The problem might not be Unicorn.

Comment: thanks for your answer, all migrations passed, but I still have an error

Comment: This was the solution for me on Unicorn. It kept using my development database credentials until I explicitly set the rake task to use production. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

just add   `config.log_level = :debug` in config/production.rb

you will get error log in log/production.log
paste output of that log so i can help you

also try `rake assets:precompile`

Comment: This solved my own problem. I believe that the OPs issue was that there was something wrong with his production rails app so this would not resolve the issue. But for those having issues with stylesheets not loading properly just run this and you should be solid